# org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have called System.exit(0) in  my class and getting this error trace in jenkins, using maven

```
Process Exit Code: 0
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: The forked VM terminated without properly saying goodbye. VM crash or System.exit called?
```

How can i get success build using System.exit(0)?

Comment: Why are you calling `System.exit(0)` in your class or in your test?

Comment: Because i have an everyhour test build and due to some logic it has to stop running in particular situation(Make an exit instead of test)

Comment: @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass() {
        if (fileUtills.isSuccessValueFromFile(FileUtills.DATA_FOR_SEO_STATUS_FILE) && Data.getCurrentHour() != 8) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

Comment: Really running a test which calls `System.exit(0)`?  And why does this test check the hour of the test? To be honest that looks really weird... Why not using a assumptions (assumeTrue()) etc? That's much better ... See https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-assumptions

Comment: Requirements from the Head. Because it has to start from a new day after success. Without an hour checking it won't start after success case anymore. They require to stop running it after success case till the next day. So it's impossible to deal with other way i assume

Comment: I use TestNg, not JUnit. Does it have something similar?

Comment: Not that I know. That's why I changed a long time ago to JUnit Jupiter (much better and more options)... sorry to say but that requirement sounds wrong..

Comment: I agree with you. But they sometimes need so curious requirements 

Comment: That sentence `Because it has to start from a new day after success. Without an hour checking it won't start after success case anymore. ` reads to me. There is an issue in your test or in your code??

Comment: It's not an issue. I just want to know how make my build success with exit. On gradle it works showing success 

Comment: But this logic in my test

Comment: If you tests does not start under some circumstances your code sounds to be buggy... if tests can not run over an over again there is some problem in there...

Comment: If you want to terminate the test execution process while it's in progress, you'll never get success. You have to try/catch this type of fail due to system.exit in jenkinsfile pipeline somehow..

Comment: But through gradle in the same case it built with success